# Pre-commit MyPy hook: How to enforce explicit types for variables?

Tags: python, python-3.8, mypy, pre-commit-hook, strong-typing

I'm using https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy

I already checked https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_file.html for the available options but couldn't find something like `disallow_untyped_variables=True`

### Example

```py
from docker.client import DockerClient
from docker import from_env
```

#### Should fail

```py
client = from_env()
```

#### Should pass

```py
client: DockerClient = from_env()
```

Comment: there is no such option -- and you don't need one anyway as mypy has type inference and can infer `client: DockerClient` (you can validate this with `reveal_type`)

Comment: Hi Anthony, thanks! I also thought the same, just wanted to be sure. Question, could you please unblock me from https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy , I'm really sorry I trolled once, won't happen again, my user: elgalu